# F1 unresponsive at start up

Tags: documentation, user-interface

I have Mathematica 11.3 installed on two PCs.  My home PC runs Linux and does not have a problem.  On my office PC (Windows 7) I find that on start up, pressing F1 to get context sensitive help is initially unresponsive.  After some delay, it then starts behaving normally.

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

I note the following:

- The firewall slows, but doesn't totally prevent access to the internet. I thought that I might be suffering from a timeout in waiting for a response from a Wolfram server, but the problem does not go away if I select the option to disable internet access.
- The virus checker probably does on-access checks on the first attempt to read any file.
- The delay after pressing F1 might be of the order of 30 s, during which period Mathematica is unresponsive.  I don't think help pops up at the end of this period, but I can then get help by pressing F1 again.
- There are other start up delays (e.g. autocomplete, starting the kernel).  I've never known starting the kernel to fail.  I'm not sure on autocomplete.
- Once start up delays are resolved, performance is good.

Comment: How long is "some delay"?  are other front-end features like auto-complete available during the delay?

Comment: @JasonB. edited to answer your comments, thanks.

Comment: Can you try to go to Edit | Preferences | Internet and disable "Allow access to the Internet"? What I definitely know is that Mathematica is unresponsive as long as it tries to log into the Wolfram Cloud. This is a long-time annoyance I experience myself.

Comment: @halirutan I tried disabling "Allow access to the Internet" and didn't see any difference.  If it makes a difference for you, I'll try it again.

Comment: How long does it take _Mathematica_ to start up in the first place? Is it running off of an HDD or SSD? I'd guess it's a combination of a somewhat slower drive, slowed down by the virus checker further on the first file access, combined with some attempts by the OS or _Mathematica_ to cache the documentation when first pressing F1.

Comment: @eyorble Mathematica start up is in line with other applications. The laptop has an SSD.

Comment: I experience exactly the same behaviour with Mma 11.3 on Win 7. Any ideas are highly appreciated.